# Quotient by a subring and not an ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, manifolds, tangent-spaces

I'm working towards understanding the Zariski tangent space of a $C^k$ manifold, using [this pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11qtbUIbnp-7ISEOjKxk6DSD1dLcGrPgv/view?usp=sharing).

The author defines $\mathcal{O}^{(k)}_{M,p}$ as the set of *germs of $C^k$ functions at $p$*, which forms a ring as well as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ (and itself, of course) with operations defined pointwise.

They further define $\mathcal{S}^{(k)}_{M,p}$ as the set of germs of $C^k$ functions *stationary at $p$*, i.e.
$\mathbf{f} \in \mathcal{S}^{(k)}_{M,p} \iff \forall(f \in \mathbf{f}).(f \circ \varphi^{-1})'(\varphi(p))=0$, for some (and any) chart $\varphi$ at $p$.
This is clearly a subring (and subalgebra) of $\mathcal{O}^{(k)}_{M,p}$, but **not an ideal** (as the author points out).

The author then asserts that $\mathcal{O}^{(k)}_{M,p} / \mathcal{S}^{(k)}_{M,p}$ is (1) a vector space that is (2) isomorphic to the space of linear derivations on $\mathcal{O}^{(k)}_{M,p}$ that vanish on $\mathcal{S}^{(k)}_{M,p}$, in turn (3) isomorphic to $T_{p}^{*}M$ the (usual) cotangent space. However, I **do not understand the quotient** $\mathcal{O}^{(k)}_{M,p} / \mathcal{S}^{(k)}_{M,p}$, since $\mathcal{S}^{(k)}_{M,p}$ is not an ideal. Is this a quotient of algebras/vector spaces? What is the implied equivalence relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a subalgebra, it is also a vector subspace. Do you know how to take the quotient by a vector subspace? It preserves the vector space structure, but the ring structure disappears.

You're doing the same thing when you take the quotient of any ring by an ideal: primarily it is a quotient of an abelian group by a subgroup. The ring structure is a "bonus" that you get when the subgroup is an ideal.

Comment: I see, so then the relation is the usual $a \sim b \iff a - b \in \mathcal{S}^{(k)}_{M,p}$ and the quotient is $\mathcal{O}^{(k)}_{M,p} / \sim$?

Comment: @terry Yes, that's right.